# intergating mastercard paymet with http://www.mastercard.com.au/

Tags: magento-1.9

I want To integrate http://www.mastercard.com.au/ master card payment within Magento. is there any free module to do that .or any build in method to do that

**Edit**
I found some paid [extension](http://www.appmerce.com/migs-vpc-mastercard-internet-gateway-service-magento.html).VkWD9b_CeiE I want to know it is ok for this